# System.Net.Mail send message without recipient

Tags: .net, email, smtp

I am using System.Net.Mail.MailMessage to create and send an email message.  For various reasons I do not want to use the .To.Add() or the .CC.Add() or the .Bcc.Add() methods to add recipients to the email.  I want to add them via the .Headers.Add() method. (This gives greater control over the recipients).

However, when I come to send the message I get an exception stating "A recipient must be specified".  It obviously does not realise that I have added recipients via the Headers.

Can anyone think of a workaround for this?  Could I somehow override the method that is validating the message and throwing the exception?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add a junk recipient to the bcc field?

Comment: It's a good idea, but there are some other processes down the line that will log all the failed sends, and I was hoping to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use that class. There is a lot alternatives on the market including opensource project.

Comment: Such as? Please elaborate on your answer so we can all use it?

Comment: Would you recommend any in particular?

Comment: MailBee (http://www.afterlogic.com/) is one alternative.  Might be expensive depending on your situation but well worth it.

Comment: Http://mailsystem.codeplex.com. You can take the necessary code from there.

Answer (score 0):

A common way of sending out mailings like this is to put the sender's address/return address (only) in the TO: field, and everything else hidden (like the BCC:). I don't know what you mean about specifying the recipients "in the headers", but your message is going to be blocked by most spam filters if it is out-of-the-ordinary, and having no visible recipients is surely that.